# Как записать функцию для возвращения id в js?

Tags: javascript

Имею задание по записи функции, которая должна принимать объект с полем `id` и возвращать его значение. 
Объект обозначил

```
let obj = {  
    key: "value",  
    id: 0,  
    caption: "Object",  
    "my key": "my value"  
}
```

А вот вернуть `id` не получается через `return getElementById`.

Буду благодарен за подсказки.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getObjectId(ob) {
  return ob.id;
}

let obj = {
  key: "value",
  id: 123,
  caption: "Object",
  "my key": "my value"
};

console.log(getObjectId(obj));
```